# fleunt-bit stackdriver returns 302 oauth2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, fluent-bit

I want to send logs to GCP with fluent-bit (and stackdriver) but getting authentication error.

```
[ info] [oauth2] HTTP Status=302
[error] [output:stackdriver:stackdriver.1] error retrieving oauth2 access token
[ warn] [output:stackdriver:stackdriver.1] token retrieval failed
```

Stackdriver uses service account key.json ("auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",)
And when I tried to curl I got the same 302 and "The document has moved..."
Does VPN that is required to access my server can be a problem? I used fluent-bit previously on different non-VPN on-prem and it worked fine. Seems like traffic is allowed.

Comment: Checked once again on another cluster where everything works fine and curl returns 302 also but somehow stackdriver can handle this and token is retrieved successfully. Something must be wrong with my server configuration that this redirection is not handled correctly.

Comment: there must something wrong with DNS, curling metadata.google.internal return 301 Moved Permamently, which seems not correct